# jQuery not working with Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some piece of code that was working individually but when I add it with the Master page, it is not working.
I thought jQuery doesn't work with Update Panel, so I removed that as well, but still no use. I believe it is some problem with Master Page.
Can anyone have a look and give any advice.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdhocTest._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server"     ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2"><b>Adhoc ArchivingTest  Page</b>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">


<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert(2);
        function isDate(txtDate) {
            var currVal = txtDate;
            if (currVal == '')
                return false;

            //Declare Regex 
            //  var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
            var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{4})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})$/
            var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

            if (dtArray == null)
                return false;

            //Checks for mm/dd/yyyy format.
            //    dtMonth = dtArray[1];
            //   dtDay = dtArray[3];
            //   dtYear = dtArray[5];


            dtMonth = dtArray[2];
            dtDay = dtArray[3];
            dtYear = dtArray[1];
            ddhours = dtArray[4];
            ddminute = dtArray[5];
            ddseconds = dtArray[6];

            if (ddhours > 24)
                return false;
            if (ddminute > 60)
                return false;
            if (ddseconds > 60)
                return false;

            if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
                return false;
            else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
                return false;

            else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31)
                return false;
            else if (dtMonth == 2) {
                var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
                if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        $(function () {



            $('#txtname').blur(function (e) {
                alert(1);
                //     var GetValue = $('#txtname').val();


                var txtVal = $('#txtname').val();

                if (isDate(txtVal))

                    alert('Valid Date format');

                else

                    alert('Invalid Date format');
            });
        });

    });


</script>


<%--
<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
    <div>
    <asp:Table ID="tblAdhocReq" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" cellpadding="3" 
            cellspacing="5" CssClass="contentheadlinemed" Font-Size="Smaller" 
            GridLines="Both" visible="true">
            <asp:TableRow>
       <asp:TableCell BackColor="#E0E0E0" HorizontalAlign="Right">ENTER REPORT VERSION DATE: : </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtname"  runat="server" />
            &nbsp&nbsp<i>(Must enter in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)</i>  

        </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell  BorderWidth="0"><asp:Label ID="Label2"  runat="server" Font-Italic="true" 
            Visible="false" ForeColor="red"/></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><%-- <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtname"></asp:TextBox>

         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>--%></div><%--</form>--%><%--</ContentTemplate>--%><%--</asp:UpdatePanel>--%><asp:Label id="ADDMsg" ForeColor="Red"  Runat="Server" Font-Bold="true"/>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two things going on here.

The first is that your controls are probably being assigned unique IDs that are not the same as the ones you gave them. You can use Milind or ZiNNED's suggestion or refer to them by class name:

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" class="text-name" runat="server" />

$(".text-name")
```

The other is that since you're using an UpdatePanel, the events will probably be detached as soon as an update happens. To account for this, use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("blur", ".text-name", function (e) {
    alert(1);

    var txtVal = $(this).val();

    if (isDate(txtVal)) {
        alert('Valid Date format');
    } else {
        alert('Invalid Date format');
    }
});
```

Comment: just one more question.In case i need to put one more validation(value should not contain special character) on another textbox(yet to be added),do I need to write another" $(function () ".Wont it get conflicted as to which function need to be called??

Comment: @user3849907 To add validation for a completely different textbox, you can just repeat the same code as above but using a different class name (or different ID) and different validation logic. There shouldn't be any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

That is because IDs for server side controls gets modified when used with master page. use ClientID to bind the event in such case:

```
$('#<%=txtname.ClientID%>').blur(function (e) {
   //rest code
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked for me.Your suggestion + JL Rishe helped me .

Answer (score 0):

Using a masterpage changes the id's of your ASP controls. To keep using the id's like you're used to, you can set the `ClientIDMode` attribute to `Static`, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```