# jQuery Autocomplete not working from within a Master page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to set up jQuery Autocomplete and I've hit a frustrating point.  I've got this code in my aspx page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /*******************************/
    /* Autocomplete the textboxes  */
    /* This responds fine if the javascript is inside the html tags and outside of the form tags, but
    /* since this page has a Master Page File I can't do that.
    /*******************************/
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtPayers.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Autocomplete.asmx/ISGetCompletionList") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#<%=hfPayer.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

and inside a rather large file which contains tab containers, tab panels, update panels, divs and the like, I have this textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPayers" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

I also have the following web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public string[] ISGetCompletionList(string prefixText)
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CLTDPL"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        List<string> Payers = new List<string>();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [PAYER_ID], [PAYER_TYPE] FROM [mos_Payer] WHERE " +
            "PAYER_TYPE like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    Payers.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["PAYER_TYPE"], sdr["PAYER_ID"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return Payers.ToArray();
    }
```

If I put this all on a test page and run it, it works fine.  However, the actual page I need it on has a Master Page File, and it's not working in that context.  Well, the first time I run it, it works fine.  But there are a few dropdowns on the page that, when something is selected, it hides and unhides other controls.  Once I do that, the autocomplete stops working.

Any ideas?  I've also seen this question:

[jQuery not working with Master Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888420/jquery-not-working-with-master-page)

and one of the answers says to use `.on()` if an update panel is involved?  I have no idea how I'd implement that, I'm still somewhat new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the answer.  If I replace:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
```

with:

```
     //On Page Load.
     $(function () {
         SetAutoComplete();
     });

     //On UpdatePanel Refresh.
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     if (prm != null) {
         prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
             if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                 SetAutoComplete();
             }
         });
     };

     function SetAutoComplete() {
```

in the javascript code and leave everything else as is, it works perfect.  Apparently it did have to do with the update panel doing a partial postback, which reassigns the unique IDs.